# Adding a Git Commit to a remote repository, regardless of not pulling first

Tags: git, github

I'm having trouble formulating my question in my head, but what I would like to do in plain English is this:

I have a github repository that is fairly old.  In the meantime, I have made many huge changes to the effect that it is the same application, but it is set within a completely different framework and layout.

I did not make these changes on top of my old program in a linear fashion.  What I mean is that I haven't bothered with Github for 2 months now, and have been working on the program completely apart from my repository and didn't even have git installed on my system.

I would like to commit my updated program, with the old version as the history of it, but without pulling my old program or doing merging of any sort.

This change is akin to a QUANTUM LEAP, in that there is (virtually) no identifiable relation to the previous version.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: my local filenames differed from the remote repository filenames, which I think makes a huge difference in the following.

---

what I ended up doing to achieve my goal was the following:

First I fetched my remote repository

```
git fetch <remote repo>
```

Then I re-based my commit (appended it onto the remote repository master branch) so as to avoid merging and ending up with an utterly unidentifiable project

```
git pull --rebase <remote repo> master
```

Afterwards, I ended up with all of the project files from my remote repository in my working directory, so I just removed them all

```
git rm
```

and then re-committed and, voila!

Answer (score 1):

```
git push --force origin master
```

Will replace the remote origin contents with the contents of your branch. Please be careful with this as the remote commits are lost.

Comment: Will I still have access to my "old history" (ie, the version of the program that is 2 months old)?  Or will that be over-written?

Comment: It will be overwritten

Comment: So, how can I just add my new version keeping the history of the old, without re-writing, but simply as an update?

Comment: `git tag` the existing master location, then force update master

Comment: Do you want to "commit" (lol) your comment as an answer?  Also, does force update mean to use the command that triggerNZ has posted in his/her answer?